# Валидная запись @font-face

Tags: css, stylus, шрифты

Спонтанно возник вопрос, есть ли отличия между этими записями:

**Stylus** версия:

```
@font-face
    font-family Avante
    src: url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff') format('woff')

    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family Avante
    src: url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff2') format('woff2')

    font-style normal
```

И:

```
@font-face
    font-family Avante
    src: url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff2') format('woff2')

    font-style normal
```

---

**CSS** версия:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Avante;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: Avante;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

И:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Avante;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/AvanteRegular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

Возникнут ли проблемы в подключении альтернативного шрифта при использовании первого варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Есть: в первом варианте строк больше. А с точки зрения подключения - никакой разницы.